# Apache, sslh, SSL certs, local app, and dockerised app

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, docker

I've got a server which has been hosting a local app (Nextcloud) for a while with no issues, behind apache (2.4).

I'm also hosting an SSH server on port 443, for which I use sslh.

My LetsEncrypt cert is provided using the following conf:-

```
<VirtualHost localhost:8443>
  ServerAdmin myemail@mailserver.com
  ServerName my.domain.name.noip.me
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/my/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/my/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

My nextcloud install is linked using the following:-

```
Alias /nextcloud /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/
<Directory /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/>
  Options FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
  php_admin_value open_basedir "/srv/http/:/dev/urandom:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/:/etc/weapps/nextcloud:/var/nextcloud/"
</Directory>
```

My sslh.cfg is as follows:-

```
listen:
(
  { host: "0.0.0.0"; port: "443"; }
)
protocols:
(
  { name: "ssh"; service: "ssh"; host: "localhost"; port: '12345"; probe: "builtin"; },
  { name: "http"; host: "localhost"; port: "80"; probe: "builtin"; },
  { name: "ssl"; host: "localhost"; port: "8443"; probe: "builtin"; },
)
```

So far this works pretty much how I'd like. Nextcloud works using my.domain.name.noip.me/nextcloud

Side note, I can even force https using the permanent redirect. Bad idea, I've figured out this is causing me headaches, but fine, I can just change my free noip, lesson learnt.

I'm now trying to add another 'folder' (so I can do my.domain.name.noip.me/app) which is running in a docker container (bitwarden, if it matters). My docker command is basically (minus all the unimportant configuration):-

```
docker run -d --name bitwarden -p 54321:80 bitwardenrs/server:latest
```

This means I can now access bitwarden using my.domain.name.noip.me:54321

I've been trying to access bitwarden using the /app subfolder by using ProxyPass, as follows:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass /app http://127.0.0.1:54321/
  ProxyPassReverse /app http://127.0.0.1:54321/
</VirtualHost>
```

This seems to work, but the redirect doesn't recognise my SSL certificate (obviously) which means my app (bitwarden) will not authenticate (when it will do so fine when accessed through my.domain.name.noip.me:54321

At this point I'm a bit lost, and not even sure what to ask. I would like to redirect all http to https, and get the ProxyPass working such that my.domain.name.noip.me/app works as https (right now I can only access it as http).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `sslh` is in my opinion more of a trick, than a real functionality. However if you use it, you should probably disable the protocol `http`. No one will ever look for HTTP on port 443.

If you want to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS modify your virtual host on port 80 to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.domain.name.noip.me
    Redirect "/" "https://my.domain.name.noip.me/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Pack everything else into the virtual host on port 8443, which is accessed through `sslh`:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:8443>
  ServerAdmin myemail@mailserver.com
  ServerName my.domain.name.noip.me
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/my/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/my/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

  # Specifies what to do when we request https://my.domain.name.noip.me/nextcloud
  Alias /nextcloud /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/
  <Directory /usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/>
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/srv/http/:/dev/urandom:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/:/etc/weapps/nextcloud:/var/nextcloud/"
  </Directory>

  # Specifies what to do when we request https://my.domain.name.noip.me/app
  ProxyPass /app http://localhost:54321/
  ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:54321/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, specifying ProxyPass inside the 8443 block works!